# How does Scala specs2 sequential keyword work

Tags: scala

As you know in scala you can do something like this :

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class ApplicationSpec extends Specification {
  sequential
}
```

And tests will be ran sequentially. However, I dont understand this language wise. What kind of a variable(?) is sequential? It is just a single word hanging there, how does it even compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sequential` is not variable; It is a method call. Take a look at the `specs2` [code base](https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/blob/64768716a12c4128690c2de5bf34324763c8168c/common/src/main/scala/org/specs2/main/Arguments.scala):

```
  def sequential: Boolean = execute.sequential
```

And why wouldn't it compile? `specs2` is mature testing framework.